# Global nonpartitioned index in Oracle

Tags: oracle, indexing, partitioning

I am reading up documentation for oracle partitioned indexes. One can find everywhere the distinction between local partitioned index and global partitioned index and that is clear to me.

I am confused that word 'global' does not imply that the index is partitioned at all.

E.g. Thomas Kyte has several examples in 'Expert Oracle Database Architecture' that looks like this:

```
create index partitioned_idx_global
on partitioned(timestamp)
GLOBAL;
Index created.
```

And one can find similar examples where the keyword GLOBAL is not followed with any partitioning description elsewhere.

There is no partitioning clause after GLOBAL which seems to be in contrast to what is allowed in [CREATE INDEX docs](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_5011.htm#SQLRF01209).

The [documentation for nonpartitioned global indexes](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/VLDBG/GUID-B42FA388-854C-4471-831A-DA371A0844BC.htm#VLDBG1080) does not make much sense to me either.

> Global nonpartitioned indexes behave just like local nonpartitioned indexes.

What the heck is 'local nonpartitioned index'? It should not even exist.

So ultimately my question is to clear the confusion. What is the difference between regular index and global nonpartitioned index? Is the syntax quoted from the book above even 'legal'?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> What the heck is 'local nonpartitioned index'?

There is no such as a "local nonpartitioned index". Seems likely that is a documentation bug. I think what they meant to say was

> "Global nonpartitioned indexes behave just like indexes on nonpartitioned tables."

So yes, the syntax quoted in Tom Kyte's book is legal.

> There is no partitioning clause after GLOBAL which seems to be in contrast to what is allowed in CREATE INDEX docs

By default GLOBAL indexes are nonpartitioned. That is, there is one index for all the partitions of the table. The main reason why we might want to do this is to enforce a unique constraint across the entire table. In practice it's rare to need to do this: Partitioning is usually restricted to data warehouses, where constraint enforcement is generally laxer, because DML is more locked down.

The documentation to which you linked shows how to create GLOBAL partitioned indexes. This is a hybrid construct which allows us to build indexes with a different partitioning scheme from that used to partition the data. To be honest I've never come across this in any site where I've worked with Partitioning. However, @matthewmcpeak suggested a scenario where it could be useful. So I am including his comment in this answer, for the benefit of future Seekers.

> A global hash partitioned index is a good way to reduce contention on very active, unique indexes of sequence values.  Normally, all inserts are on the right side of the index.  If there are many inserts from many parallel sessions, there can be a lot of contention -- with each session causing more work for the others (since they'll all need to apply a lot of UNDO to backout committed changes to get consistent block reads).  An old solution to this was to use a `REVERSE` index.  Now, a global hash partitioned index is better -- reduces contention without blowing up physical I/Os.
>   The table itself does not need to be partitioned for the technique to apply.

Comment: Ok thx. So does that mean that the global nonpartitioned index created such as from Tom's book would be the same regardless whether there is the 'GLOBAL' keyword at the end or it is missing? The indexes are identical?

Comment: A global hash partitioned index is a good way to reduce contention on very active, unique indexes of sequence values.  Normally, all inserts are on the right side of the index.  If there are many inserts from many parallel sessions, there can be a lot of contention -- with each session causing more work for the others (since they'll all need to apply a lot of UNDO to backout committed changes to get consistent block reads).  An old solution to this was to use a `REVERSE` index.  Now, a global hash partitioned index is better -- reduces contention without blowing up physical I/Os.

Comment: @matthewmcpeak - thanks for the info. I hope I remember this if I ever find myself with many parallel sessions inserting into a partitioned table. Never came across it before, no doubt due to the sheltered life I lead ;-)

Comment: The table itself does not need to be partitioned for the technique to apply.  :)

Comment: @matthewmcpeak - oh that is interesting, I will have a play with that later this evening. I have included the text of your comment in my answer because I think it's worth preserving. Hope you don't mind

Answer (score 2):

In principle Oracle provides three types of indexes.

- **Global Nonpartitioned Indexes**: You have one index which spans over all partitions of the table. If you alter a table partition then such index gets `UNUSABLE` and you have to rebuild it.
- **Local Partitioned Indexes**: This index is partitioned in the same way as the partitions of the base table. Each index partition belongs solely to one table partition.
- **Global Partitioned Indexes**: This index is partitioned but the partition key is different to partition key of base table (which can be also a nonpartitioned table). For example, you could have the table not partitioned or partitioned by RANGE but the index is partitioned by LIST of a different column.

Most common are *Global nonpartitioned* and *Local partitioned* indexes. Actually I cannot imagine any use case where a *Global partitioned* Index would make sense, they might be useful only in very special circumstances.